# Using NEWID() with CTE to produce random subset of rows produces odd results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, newid

I'm writing some SQL in a stored procedure to reduce a dataset to a limited random number of rows that I want to report on.

The report starts with a `Group` of `Users` and a filter is applied to specify the total number of random rows required (`@SampleLimit`).

To achieve the desired result, I start by creating a CTE (temp table) with:

- The `top(@SampleLimit)` applied
- `group by UserId` (as the UserID appears multiple times)
- `order by NEWID()` to put the results in a random order

SQL:

```
; with cte_temp as 
       (select top(@SampleLimit) UserId from QueryResults 
        where (GroupId = @GroupId)
        group by UserId order by NEWID())
```

Once I have this result set, I then delete any results where the UserId is `NOT IN` the CTE created in the previous step.

```
delete QueryResults 
where (GroupId = @GroupId) and (UserId not in(select UserId from cte_temp))
```

The issue that I'm having is that from time to time, I get more results than specified in the `@SampleLimit` and other times it works exactly as expected.

I've tried breaking up the SQL and executing it outside the application and I cannot reproduce the issue.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with what I am doing that could explain why I occasionally get more results that I request?

**For completeness - my re-factored solution based on below answer:**

```
select top(@SampleLimit) UserId into #T1
from  QueryResults
where (GroupId = @GroupId)
group by UserId
order by NEWID() 

delete QueryResults 
where (GroupId = @GroupId) and (UserId not in(select UserId from #T1))
```

Comment: I would suggest that `SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@SampleLimit) ...` will work faster than `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Do you get more results left with after you `DELETE ... WHERE UserID not IN (...)`?

Comment: @Stoleg yes, the delete leave more distinct users than I've specified. I'll test the execution plan for your suggestion above

Comment: @Stoleg that's correct, the first query gets my random sample set and any users outside that set will be deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undeterministic how many times the `SELECT` statement involving `NEWID()` will be executed.

If you get a nested loops anti semi join between `QueryResults` and `cte_temp` and there is no spool in the plan it will likely be re-evaluated as many times as there are rows in `QueryResults` this means that for each outer row the set that is being compared against with `NOT IN` may be entirely different.

Instead of using a CTE you can materialize the results into a temporary table to avoid this.

```
INSERT INTO #T
SELECT TOP(@SampleLimit) UserId
FROM   QueryResults
WHERE  ( GroupId = @GroupId )
GROUP  BY UserId
ORDER  BY NEWID()
```

Then reference that in the `DELETE`

Comment: This seems to be working. I will do some more tests and confirm shortly but I've not got an incorrect count since implementing the above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it fixed the issue and I re-factored it into a single delete query that I've posted with the question fr completeness.

Comment: @Tanner - Your refactoring into a sub query isn't guaranteed to work either. The only way of ensuring it is only evaluated once is to execute it once yourself and store the results (e.g. in a `#temp` or `@table` variable)

Comment: I've refactored again into a temp table as you suggest & the solution above is updated. Thanks again.